# How I can access $data variable of a Mixin.js file from Store.js using Vue.Js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Mixin file like this:

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            analysisTime: "nothing",
            phantomPrefix: "One more",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        isGeneric: function() {
            return this.phantomPrefix
        },
    }
}
```

Whenever I call **Mixin.js** its methods are accessible but the ***$data*** variable is returning undefined.

For example, Whenever I called **isGeneric** function it's returning **undefined** instead of 'one more' because it's returns *this.phantomPrefix*.

Ps: If I access the same method of Mixin.js file from another component let's say Example.Vue it's working fine for me.

I have imported the Mixin file in store.js like:

```
import Mixin from "./mixins/Mixin";
```

and calling method like this: `Mixin.methods.isGeneric()`

Store.js file contains:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import tmpMixin from "./mixins/tmpMixin";

Vue.use(Vuex);
let vue_plugins = [];

export default new Vuex.Store({
    plugins: vue_plugins,
    state:{},
    action:{
        get_snippet_data_using_tomograph: function(data) {
            let output = tmpMixin.methods.isGeneric()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a code usage example in the store?  Technically you could do `let component = new Vue(Mixin)` and `component.isGeneric()` would work. But it seems like a wrong pattern to use.

Comment: @Kunukn - I have updated the question sharing the code here also 

`import Vue from "vue";
// const Vue = () => import("vue");
import Vuex from "vuex";
import tmpMixin from "./mixins/tmpMixin";

Vue.use(Vuex);
let vue_plugins = [];

export default new Vuex.Store({
    plugins: vue_plugins,
    state:{},
    action:{
        get_snippet_data_using_tomograph: function(data) {
            let tomograph_output = tmpMixin.methods.isGeneric()
        }
    }
});
`

Answer (score 0):

Vue mixins are made for Vue components, it's not compatible with a Vuex module.

A mixins expect a Vue component instance, which is not provided by Vuex when you import it like this.

If you need to have a reusable code between a Vuex store and Vue components, you still can create a simple js file that exports a functions. But it won't be reactive or have a current state because it's not a Vue component.

Comment: Can we use `eventbus` method to pass the value from store.js to any component function?

Comment: No need for that, every component have access to the store via `this.$store`. If you need to listener to a property in the state, just use `this.$store.state.myProp` and you have access to it from the component :) And it's reactive